# Can anyone explain why 'two' > 'seven billion' equates to True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

How does python evaluate which string is greater than another?  In the case of integers we know that seven billion is larger, but what is the case with raw strings?

Comment: use `len` and read the docs or did you mean to convert the name of a number to an actual number? it is a bit confusing what you mean by _bigger_

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode to measure the number of characters in a string, compare which one is bigger (the word can be interpreted many ways in this specific context)

Comment: What is your measure of a `bigger string`?

Comment: @Matiiss Yeah ok. I just focused on the title, and `len` doesn't help explain it.

Comment: Its called a lexicographic comparison. It checks if `t` > `s` and then it returns true.

Comment: Python just guesses. Sometimes it gets it right, e.g., 'ten' > 'nine'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Using the < or > operator to compare strings in comparison will compare the unicode values in each word in alphabetical order. The unicode value of 't' is 116, while the unicode value of 's' is 115, hence `'two' > 'seven billion'` returns `True`.

You can check the unicode value of a character using `ord()`:

```
print(ord(u't'))
print(ord(u's'))
```